ReferenceError: process is not defined reactJs
I am new to react. Just trying to run application,
Facing below issue showing in browser console:

Error showing in browser

I have tryied below solutions:

react-scripts version : 5 did not worked
"react-error-overlay": "6.0.9" did not worked
"resolutions": { "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9" }, not working

tryied all possible google solution but non of them working.

process is a server-side object that doesn't work in the browser. Only in Node. What code is causing this?

If you're not using process yourself, I suspect you're using some Node.js internal module or a npm package that's not intended to be used on the browser.
